# Metaclasses via global options

Tags: document-classes, class-options

### Vision

I am making a small, custom LaTeX class for my organization. I want this class to support a couple different kinds of documents: articles, and reports. I want to actually inherit from the `article`, or `report` class, depending on provided global options.

I know this sounds a bit weird, but I *think* I have a good enough reason. The two documents will share common elements, like a common coverpage and other kinds of markings, and I want to share common code for those features. Still, there are other "category-specific" changes I'd like to make (default font size, shorter or longer form default settings, etc.)

I could accomplish this by just inheriting from one class, and overriding default options depending on what global options the user passes. But I'd like this to be modular and easily modifiable for the future (maybe a `book` format, etc.)

### Attempt

This is what I've got so far.

```
%
% custom.cls
%

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{custom}[...]

% Use key-value options for article/report specification
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}

\DeclareBoolOption{report}
\DeclareComplementaryOption{article}{report}

% I _hope_ this processes key-value options, and no others
\ProcessKeyvalOptions{custom}\relax

\ifcustom@report
    \input{custom-report}
\else
    \input{custom-article}
\fi
```

```
%
% custom-report.tex
%

\message{This is a report!}
\message{Class Options: \@classoptionslist}

\ExecuteOptions{11pt,letterpaper}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{report}
```

```
%
% custom-article.tex
%

\message{This is an article!}
\message{Class Options: \@classoptionslist}

\ExecuteOptions{12pt,letterpaper}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{article}
```

### Problem

I get all kinds of weird errors doing this. I can successfully pass `report` or `article` to `\documentclass[...]{custom}`, and the proper "class" is loaded. But when I try to add *other* options, such as `twocolumn`, I'll get errors indicating a missing `\begin{document}`, even though I'll have a `\begin{document}`.

Is this kind of behavior supported? Is there a "right" way to do what I'm trying to do? I'd really prefer not to write separate `.cls` files...

Comment: Why not the other way around? Write multiple class files that load common code placed in a code file. E.g., `JoesArticle.cls` and `JoesReport.cls` both `\input` a `JoesTitlepage.tex`.